# the program asks for the students name and his grade at the same time

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program which asks for 6 students' names and grades, and calculates it (A, B, C, F etc..)

I have an annoying bug that I cannot solve.
If you run it and see the output you will know what I mean: it skips asking for the second student name.

```
import java.util.*;

public class grading {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        String a, b, c, d, e, f = "";
        int mid1, mid2, finl, total = 0;
        int mid12, mid22, finl2, total2 = 0;
        int mid13, mid23, finl3, total3 = 0;
        int mid14, mid24, finl4, total4 = 0;
        int mid15, mid25, finl5, total5 = 0;
        int mid16, mid26, finl6, total6 = 0;
        String g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6 = "0";

        System.out.println ("Enter you first student name :");
        a = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("His first midterm grade [out of 25] :");
        mid1 = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("His second midterm grade [out of 25] :");
        mid2 = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("His final test grade [out of 50] :");
        finl = kb.nextInt();

        total = mid1 + mid2 + finl;

        ///////////////////////// Student 1

        System.out.println ("Enter you second student name :");
        b = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("His first midterm grade [out of 25] :");
        mid12 = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("His second midterm grade [out of 25] :");
        mid22 = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("His final test grade [out of 50] :");
        finl2 = kb.nextInt();

        total2 = mid12 + mid22 + finl2;

        ////////////////////// Student 2

        System.out.println ("Enter you third student name :");
        c = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("His first midterm grade [out of 25] :");
        mid13 = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("His second midterm grade [out of 25] :");
        mid23 = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("His final test grade [out of 50] :");
        finl3 = kb.nextInt();

        total3 = mid13 + mid23 + finl3;

        ///////////////////// Student 3

        System.out.println ("Enter you fourth student name :");
        d = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("His first midterm grade [out of 25] :");
        mid14 = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("His second midterm grade [out of 25] :");
        mid24 = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("His final test grade [out of 50] :");
        finl4 = kb.nextInt();

        total4 = mid14 + mid24 + finl4;

        //////////////////////// Student 4

        System.out.println ("Enter you fifth student name :");
        e = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("His first midterm grade [out of 25] :");
        mid15 = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("His second midterm grade [out of 25] :");
        mid25 = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("His final test grade [out of 50] :");
        finl5 = kb.nextInt();

        total5 = mid15 + mid25 + finl5;

        /////////////////// Student 5


        System.out.println ("Enter you sixth student name :");
        f = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("His first midterm grade [out of 25] :");
        mid16 = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("His second midterm grade [out of 25] :");
        mid26 = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("His final test grade [out of 50] :");
        finl6 = kb.nextInt();

        total6 = mid16 + mid26 + finl6;

        /////////////// Student 6 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `kb.next()` instead of `kb.nextLine()`. That should work.

When you press enter after typing the int value, since it is not an integer, it gets consumed as the value for your `kb.nextLine()` so it is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Your input consists of ints and lines.  `nextInt` will give you the next `int` supplied, consuming a newline if it needs to.  However if you follow a `nextInt` with a `newLine`, the `newline` will be satisfied with carriage return used to input the `int`.

The solution is to add

```
kb.nextLine();
```

after reading the final grade for each student.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a new Scanner for every reading.

```
a = new Scanner (System.in).nextLine();
mid1 = new Scanner (System.in).nextInt();
mid2 = new Scanner (System.in).nextInt();
finl = new Scanner (System.in).nextInt();
b = new Scanner (System.in).nextLine();
...
```